# Supporting Server side validation with ServiceStack.Razor

Tags: servicestack

I have a Service which, depending on content type, either uses Razor to return HTML or returns JSON.  When in HTML mode I want to support server side (non-JavaScript) validation of Forms.  I wish to rely on the repository for validation, if the repo returns an error I re-display the form along with the error message from the repo.

The model I am using is this:

- in json mode simply throw an Exception
- in HTML mode return a response containing both the partially created object and the response status.

This allows me to re-display the form using the same View that I would use when editing an existing object and also display the error message contained in Model.ResponseStatus.Message.

My question: Does anyone have any thoughts on how well I am using the facilities provided by ServiceStack?  Is there a better, cleaner, simpler way?